# Excel find in workbook shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for Excel to open the find dialog with search within workbook selected?

If not, is there a way to bind this functionality, say overwriting the format cell shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+F`?

Comment: `Ctrl+F` ? Why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Vylix Ctrl+F does a find in the current sheet. I would like the workbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I misread the initial question as asking for* **Find in workbook**, *instead of the shortcut. My proposed shortcut is just below these steps.*

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find window.
2. Then click on **Options** to expand advanced settings.
3. In "Within" dropdown, select **Workbook**.

Now your search will be applied to the workbook instead of current sheet.

This selection will persist until you close Excel.

---

This is *not* really a shortcut, but can work using only keyboard.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> then start typing

These are the exact shortcuts for the same steps mentioned earlier in the post.

[image: Find in workbook]

Comment: Hi Vylix, thanks for your answer, I already knew this is how to search within a wokbook but I would like a shortcut for this. It's annoying to have to select Workbook each time from the dropdown.

Comment: @kjhf I added a workaround, which can be used as shortcut if used in quick succession - if you got used to it.

Comment: Add an Alt + N to the end in order to return to the find box and that's a nice compromise :)